# What is the Libertarian party perspective on second hand smoke?

Tags: united-states, libertarian-party

Several cities in California have or are considering instituting public smoking bans that are quite restrictive by citing the health concerns of secondhand smoke, i.e. [Calabasas](https://www.cityofcalabasas.com/our-city/secondhand-smoke-control-ordinance/smoking-ordinance-faqs), [Laguna Beach](https://www.ocregister.com/2017/05/09/laguna-beach-becomes-first-city-in-orange-county-to-ban-smoking-in-town/)

How is 'pollution' from one person's second hand smoke, the possible negative health benefits of said pollution, and the freedom of people to breathe 'clean air' to be addressed from a Libertarian perspective.

Comment: It should be firstly aksed, if 'freedom of people to breathe clean air' is a part of libertarian perspective. Libertarianism concentrate mostly on negative (freedom from) and not positive (freedom to) liberty.

Comment: Recommend shifting this to "predominate Libertarian" perspective. There are numerous people out there that would espouse different ideals, all claiming to be libertarian. With facts, polling, etc, the leading Libertarian perspective could be surmised.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Libertarian Party of Missouri published an [editorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140819032711/https://lpmo.org/blog/glenn/Libertarian-Principles-Rights-and-Smoking-Bans) on this issue. I won't suggest that it represents the global view of all Libertarian platforms, but it is at least illustrative of how Libertarian candidates and parties are thinking about this.

Overview:

- A person has the right to choose whether they smoke or not.
- A person has the right to choose whether people smoke on their property or not. So it is reasonable for restaurant owners (or others) to institute bans which are applicable to their property.
- The government has the right to institute smoking bans for government buildings.
- The government should not institute smoking bans for non-governmental buildings (because that infringes on the rights of the property owner).

How about the health or environmental aspects of smoking? The problem arises that smoking could harm nearby people through second-hand smoke. Although I did not find any official or unofficial statements from a Libertarian Party source, an [opinion piece](http://www.nydailynews.com/opinion/time-snuff-public-smoking-article-1.1470131) in the New York Daily times suggests that since smoking produces negative externalities it is fair for the government to regulate it (to protect the rights of non-smokers who would be harmed by others' choices).

Comment: The two articles seem to be at odds with one another. The first defines public in the sense of buildings but doesn't address public spaces like sidewalks, parks, beaches, etc. and rails against such bans.  The second cogently advocates for the rights of non-smokers.  I suppose this is an internal party battle that isn't as yet settled.

Comment: @CramerTV The article defines public as owned by the government not just open to the public. It would be ok for the government to ban smoking on sidewalks, parks and beaches that are owned by the government. Some parks and beaches are owned by private companies, neighborhood associations, etc. and it would be the right of those organizations to allow or ban smoking.

Comment: @JonK, fair enough.  They specifically said buildings, but it was in the context of property so it is a fair interpretation that 'public spaces' owned by the government could be included.  It does seem quite contrary to the current leanings within the party though.

Comment: @CramerTV - These aren't analytical discussions, so I would not be surprised (or alarmed) by them not lining up exactly.

Comment: @CramerTV It's worth noting that government ownership of sidewalks, parks, and beaches isn't really the Libertarian Party ideal, just how things happen to be currently.

Comment: So libertarians believe that governments should regulate externalities?

Comment: @user4951 That would be overly broad. All I could find is an opinion piece from a non-official source. It's illustrative, at best.

Comment: It seems Libertarian positions strongly hinge on the concept of ownership and absolute control of owned things. Those not owning... their problem.

Comment: @CramerTV there’s no danger from second hand smoking *outdoors* because the smoke is quickly diluted by fresh air. So it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 14):

I have previously seen a number of libertarian sources (e.g. [this blog](http://libertarianjew.blogspot.com/2013/09/a-libertarian-argument-in-favor-of.html)) convincingly argue that **imposing second-hand smoke danger on others constitutes a violation of non-aggression principle** and **therefore banning smoking is a valid libertarian approach**.

It may be a bit murky in regards to people who have a choice to not be near a smoker, e.g. a patron of a private business who can choose to take their business elsewhere - in which case the freedom of smokers and of business owner may outweigh the non-smoker's freedom. **But it seems much more clear-cut in regards to people who do NOT have such an easy choice**; for example employees of smoking-OK restaurant; or neighbours of smoking-OK building; or people visiting public spaces.

As such, a government action to ban smoking can be argued to be a legitimate libertarian approach, as defense of victims who suffer from someone violating non-aggression principle - including in private businesses for the sake of their employees.

*(you can think of it, for simile's sake, in terms of "is the government allowed to ban hitting you with a stick?").*

Comment: P.S. One problem with this topic is that in 99% of smoking related discussions around libertarianism, most discussions of negative externalities center around medical cost of treating smokers and **not second-hand smoke**; which presents its own philosophical dilemma for libertarians in real world (theoretical solution: don't spend government money on treating smoking-caused disease. Good luck applying that theoretical solution in real world).

Comment: How would it not be in line with libertarian views to say "if it is a privately owned restaurant, it is everyone's own choice and responsibility  to seek patronage or employment there or not"?

Comment: It's a pretty extreme form of libertarianism that allows an employer to endanger the health and safety of its employees.

Comment: @rackandboneman - patronage, yes. employment, iffy - there are significant costs to changing employment in reality (unlike changing where you eat).

Comment: Many employment opportunities are inherently risky, whether it's fishing, manufacturing, logging, construction, etc. All are arguably more dangerous to the employee than secondhand smoke. And what about jobs that require [sitting all day?](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/adult-health/expert-answers/sitting/faq-20058005)

Comment: @pwcnorthrop - "inherently" being the key word. There's nothing inherent about being assaulted by tobacco smoke while serving lunch, any more than being assaulted with fists. There's no doubt that prohibiting the latter is well within libertarian philosophy, as a matter of fact is core to it under "NAP".

Comment: If you know that it is a smoking establishment, then yes, it is an inherent risk of the job. You can make the informed decision whether to work there or not. This isn't someone pummeling while I walk down the street. If you are a boxer, you agree to be "assaulted with fists" as part of the job description. It's a choice. The libertarian philosophy is about letting people make that choice, whether being exposed to the risk is worth it, just like the other jobs I mentioned.

Comment: @pwcnorthrop - by your argument, being hit when working in a bar is an inherent risk of the job. Yet, we don't just allow bar owners to permit people to assault bar workers. You need to explain the difference before asserting that it is in any way different.

Comment: I know of no bar that allows, or would want to allow, the hitting of bartenders. I don't see how being hit in the bar could be classified as an inherent risk. But even if they wanted to start a "Fight Club" type bar, so be it, though I'd imagine they'd have a hard time attracting servers in that scenario. With smoking, there's plenty of people that don't mind second-hand smoke (e.g. smokers themselves), some who would work in that environment for a higher wage, and some who would almost never work in a smoking room.

Comment: The primary difference I refer to in my last comment is the "on the street" part. I agree, from a NAP-type argument, that blowing smoke in my face on the street is akin to being assaulted with fists on the street. It is changes when you decide to go to a private business, either as a patron or employee, and know full well what you are getting yourself into and agreeing to the risks thereof.

Comment: @pwcnorthrop - drunks are known to start fights in the bar. Including hitting employees. Again, you are asserting that there's something meaningfully different between the right to assault a bar employee with a fist and a right to assault a bar employee with a cigarette smoke. I asset that there's no difference between the two; and therefore just as the former is prohibited under NAP so should be the latter.

Comment: Only if a fundamental employer-employee asymmetry is assumed?

Comment: No bar *allows* drunks to start fights. Sometimes they do and get thrown out. I do not assert that there is something morally different between a fist and smoke. I assert that the choice should be allowed to be made by the people involved. Just as no one would assert a boxing match violates NAP, although punching someone on the street is. I assert that smoking lounges don't violate NAP because everyone agrees to be there, although blowing smoke in my face on the street does. Consensual sex doesn't violate NAP, rape does. Agreeing to work for wages doesn't violate NAP, slavery does.

Comment: @pwcnorthrop - you're making incorrect parallels. Boxing match is equivalent to two smokers in a closed off room blowing smoke at each other. An employee being smoked at is equivalent to a boxer at a match punching the referee or a spectator or whatever you call the person carrying bout count placards. Just as the latter is illegal (including under NAP libertarian principles), so should be smoking around employees.